# ionic3 google map not showing in navstack

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I can't show google map in ionic 3 application when using tabs with link.

i got 3tabs and in 1 tab i have a link too google map for users.

lets assume my current tab name is  `AddressPage`,
when i click on link to show google map , i will go to  `MapPage` with `nav.push()`
and my  ion-header loads but i cant see google map in middle of screen and it shows my previous page `AddressPage` content in middle of map page.

i'm sure i have google map in there because i have a button in ion content that shows the current lat\lng of the marker and it works , but the map is not there.

i used safari to debug the application and when i make all ion-app visibility to none , google map is showing.
so i think its some css problem with ionic and google map sdk.

BTW i can show map when i'm not using tabs and its my home page , so i only have this problem in this situation.

Can any1 help me for this?
i searched a lot in stackoverflow and ionic forum and i almost did everything i saw on the internet.
from adding css like adding nav-decorator css to hide or ....

Thank in advance for any help !

its my ionic info :

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

 ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.isEdit = this.navParams.get('isEdit');
    this.loadMap();
}
```

this is my map page.ts code

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.isEdit = this.navParams.get('isEdit');
    this.loadMap();
}

//load the map
loadMap() {
    //google map options
    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
        camera: {
            target: this.mapCenter,
            zoom: 16,
            tilt: 10,
        },
        mapTypeId: 'ROADMAP',
        controls: {
            myLocationButton: true,
            zoom: false
        },
    };
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);
    this.showLoading(null);
    this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
        .subscribe((resp) => {
            this.hideLoading();

        });

}
```

this is my map page css

```
 #map_canvas {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
  }
```

this is my map.html

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title text-center>
        انتخاب آدرس
    </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
 <ion-content>

<div id="map_canvas" >

</div>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you work with **tabs**, this solution works for you to **visible** and hide google map between different tabs.

```
initialMapLoad: boolean = true;

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.loadMap();
}

ionViewWillEnter(){
  if (!this.initialMapLoad) {
    // reset div & *then* set visibility to smooth out reloading of map
    this.map.setDiv('map_canvas');
    this.map.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    this.initialMapLoad = false;
  }
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
  // unset div & visibility on exit
  this.map.setVisible(false);
  this.map.setDiv(null);
}
```

Other than this you can use Google maps Javascript API. It works very well everywhere.

If still, you have any issue, **please feel free to comment**.

Comment: thanks for reply. i solved this problem from a topic i cant remember. bu the point was to hide navstacks when going to google map. the map was loading ok if i had maximum of two navstacks and the third was google map, but problem was when i had more than 3 nav stacks and then i used google map,so i hide all navstacks before google map on leave.and show them again on will enter.